# How to acces files from Storage/App directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to access the file `storage/app/15573877669649.jpg`.

### Code to upload the file

```
$file = $request->file('cover_image');
$fileName = time().rand(111, 9999).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk('local')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file));
```

### Code to retrieve the file in the `blade.php` file

```
<img src = "{{ URL::to('/').Storage::url($article->coverImage) }}" alt="image">
```

which returns

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/15573877669649.jpg
```

I have tried to manually put `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/15573877669649.jpg` but it's also not working

Comment: is there any error ??

Comment: Please refer to this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Laravel's `Storage::('local')` is not accessible from public; the `Storage::('public')` is the one will be publish by command `php artisan storage:link`

So for your sample code, you can do it like this:

Uploading file

```php
$file = $request->file('cover_image');
$fileName = time().rand(111, 9999).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file));
```

In blade.php file

```php
<img src = "{{ URL::to('/').Storage::disk('public')->url($article->coverImage) }}" alt="image">

// Or simpler
<img src = "{{ asset("/storage/$article->coverImage") }}" alt="image">
```

More detail of the 'disk' please check config file in `/config/filesystems.php`, and refer the the [Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk) section of official document

---

And, remember to enable the follow symlinks settings in your web server

```
// Apache:
<Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

// Nginx:
{
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Open commandline inside your project
- Type in `php artisan storage:link`

Your files will now be accessible under "/storage/file.jpg"

`/` leads to `public`

`/storage/` leads you to `storage/app/public` thanks to link

Comment: Thanks, but this is already done, after doing all this I have raised the question. Do you think there is any issue in my code to get the file??